# nested mail merge options

Tags: .net, ms-word, nested, mailmerge

I need to perform an automated mail merge using .net driven from an asp.net front end.

The mail merge needs to support nested fields, I have come across a product form [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/howto-use-nested-mail-merge-regions.html) but it's highly unlikely that my company would purchase it given its price.

Are there any other alternative options that support nested data in a way or similar to the aspose product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly do you mean with "nested" fields. But.. may be this could be helpful, and it's free. It's called NTemplates and it's free and open source. It's hosted at codeplex.com: [www.ntemplates.codeplex.com](http://ntemplates.codeplex.com)

Comment: Gonzalo, ntemplates is a pretty awesome library, but it doesn't work on asp.net applications.

Comment: Yes, I know. The issues have been fixed. I was using it in a winforms app when developed it but now I'm using it in an combined webforms - mvc app. I have added some features like image and link handling. Unfortunatelly I had to remove the official release but the code is current and you can download it. I will add a new release when I find some time. Thanks for the feedback.